# DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND is not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi i have the following stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `p25`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `p25`()
BEGIN
DECLARE b BOOLEAN;
DECLARE a VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t FROM sample_table;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET b = TRUE;

OPEN cur_1;
lbl:LOOP

IF b = TRUE THEN 
    LEAVE lbl;
END IF;
IF NOT b= TRUE THEN 
        FETCH cur_1 INTO a; 
END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_1;
END$$
```

the select statements actually returns 5 rows 
but the above procedure after one row is fetched it is not looping through other rows.
and the b value is never set to true and it is going to infinite loop because of that. 
is there any problem with  my code.
please some one help me..

I got the solution for this, thanks for helping me.
i think the way i am checking the values is wrong.
So now, i want to fetch the values from some other table depending on the row value fetched. how can i print the result like
||current row value ||  the values fetched from other table||
as a result for all the rows fetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change -

```
IF NOT b= TRUE THEN 
  FETCH cur_1 INTO a;
```

with -

```
IF b IS NULL THEN 
  FETCH cur_1 INTO a;
```

Try this code -

```
DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE a VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t FROM sample_table;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b = 1;

OPEN cur_1;

REPEAT
  FETCH cur_1 INTO a;
  IF NOT b THEN
    -- do something:
    ...
    ...
    ...
  END IF;
UNTIL b END REPEAT;

CLOSE cur_1;
```

Comment: yes i did that also. the prblem is b is never set to true, and it is going to infinte loop bcoz of that. there are 5 rows the select statement returns, but still it is giving me only first row.

Comment: There are variants. It depends on what you need. You can execute SELECT...INTO statement and WHERE condition like this - 'SELECT column1 INTO var1 FROM table 2 WHERE id = a;'. Or try to avoid using cursors - write one SELECT query with JOIN clause to get data from two tables.

Answer (score 7):

One of the reason could be that you might have used select into statements inside your cursor again, which sets your handler value to be 1 for those nested select statements inside the cursor loop. You can reset handler value to 0 after select statements used inside and move the handler condition just next to the FETCH command.
Example:

```
...
BEGIN
DECLARE cursor_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cursor_finished = 1;
...
open table_cursor;
get_row: LOOP
  FETCH table_cursor INTO v_variable1, v_variable3;
  IF cursor_finished = 1 THEN 
    LEAVE get_row;
  END IF;
  ....
  Select id into v_id from sometable; -- this sets cursor_finished to 1.
  SET cursor_finished = 0; -- hence reset this value for cursor.
  ....
END
```

Comment: this is a helpful comment that extra `SELECT INTO` can mess up the loop.

Answer (score 0):

- Continue handler for not found triggering from other statements used in body, like select into query not returning so it is triggering and setting b=TRUE, that's why it is not working as expected
- For loop it check and trigger when we user "FETCH" statement

> Structure should be something like, location of following code is important: "SET v_finished = FALSE;"

```
DECLARE v_finished BOOLEAN;
DECLARE cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM sample_table;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = TRUE;

OPEN cur_1;
lbl_loop_for_cur_1: LOOP

    SET v_finished = FALSE;
    FETCH cur_1 INTO v_col_1, v_col_2;
    IF v_finished = TRUE THEN
        LEAVE lbl_loop_for_cur_1;
    END IF;
    
    -- <your other queries for loop body>
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_1;
```